# Changing lower limit of graph y-axis when x is a discrete variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I am trying to adjust the y-axis of this graph so that it starts at 1 instead of 0. What's the best way to do this?

One solution I have used in the past for this type of issue is to use geom_rect instead of geom_bar. However, this does not work here because the x-axis is not continuous.

I have tried to create a separate, continuous x-variable, but it really messes up the formatting of the graph.

I would like for it to look like this graph, but with the lower y-limit at 1 and each bar moved down 1  unit to match.

[image]

Code:

```
groups %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(message = fct_relevel(message, "Personal", "General"),
         enviroattitudeshalf = fct_relevel(enviroattitudeshalf, "Low Environmental Attitudes", "High Environmental Attitudes")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = message, y = mean)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5, fill = "003900") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, digits = 1), vjust = -2)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9)) + 
  labs(title = "Environment: Evaluations of Personal and General Convincingness",
       y = "Rating",
       x = "Personal evaluation or general evaluation") + 
  ylim(0, 8) +
  facet_wrap(~enviroattitudeshalf)
```

Data:

```
structure(list(enviroattitudeshalf = c("Low Environmental Attitudes", 
"Low Environmental Attitudes", "High Environmental Attitudes", 
"High Environmental Attitudes"), message = c("General", "Personal", 
"General", "Personal"), mean = c(3.89473684210526, 3.37894736842105, 
4.43636363636364, 5.10909090909091), se = c(0.145460372156746, 
0.19522803582675, 0.160549137262631, 0.171509247396541)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(enviroattitudeshalf = c("High Environmental Attitudes", 
"Low Environmental Attitudes"), .rows = structure(list(3:4, 1:2), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coord_cartesian` :

```
library(tidyverse)

groups %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(message = fct_relevel(message, "Personal", "General"),
         enviroattitudeshalf = fct_relevel(enviroattitudeshalf, "Low Environmental Attitudes", "High Environmental Attitudes")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = message, y = mean)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5, fill = "003900") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, digits = 1), vjust = -2)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9)) + 
  labs(title = "Environment: Evaluations of Personal and General Convincingness",
       y = "Rating",
       x = "Personal evaluation or general evaluation") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 8)) +  
  facet_wrap(~enviroattitudeshalf)
```

[image]

Comment: This does answer the question I posted but is not exactly what I am looking for. I have posted a more precise follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66084411/changing-lower-limit-of-graph-y-axis-when-x-is-a-discrete-variable-without-cutti